# Angularjs: ng-repeat array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

in angularjs i want show a table with two columns: the header of the first column is "Type" and the second column is "Product".

In the controller i have the following structure (in the chrome debugger):

```
products: Array[0]
    drink:Array[12]
      0: Object
      1: Object
      ....
      ....
```

So i have a "products" array with "drink" key with associate an array of objects (12 items)

In  angularjs, with ng-repeats, how can i show as many rows as the number of products items (and show in the Type column the "drink" key) and in the column Product all the objects (only the name) associated with the key?

Thanks

Comment: Do provide us with the snippet of code of what you have attempted :)

Comment: i don't have tried because i don't know how to do

Comment: If you know how to do a basic ng-repeat, this is not hard to achieve. You should try a few easy ones, and you will find the solution quickly. Do one ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `id` and `name` put the attribute name which your object have:

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="obj in products[0].drink">
<td>{{ obj.id}}</td>
<td>{{ obj.name}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```